# Flex (lexical analyzer) not recognizing or operator

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I have a problem with flex. It doesn't recognize the or operator in this rule:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT} | {CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ [0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ {...}
```

If I split it into three rules then it is recognized:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT}  {...}
{CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ { ...}
[0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ {...}
```

To explain myself better the pattern I am trying to recognize is:

```
CORRECT [1-9]*_[1-9]*0
```

And in order for flex to recognize the CORRECT pattern only when it is not surrounded by other characters I have to add these three rules.

Full flex code:

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
int num_lines=1;

%}

CORRECT [1-9]*_[1-9]*0

%%
{CORRECT} { printf("CORRECT TOKEN:%s\n",yytext); }

[0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT}  { printf("ERROR %d:Unidentified symbol: %s\n",num_lines,yytext);}
{CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ { printf("ERROR %d:Unidentified symbol: %s \n",num_lines,yytext);}
[0-9A-Za-z]+{CORRECT}[0-9A-Za-z]+ { printf("ERROR %d:Unidentified symbol: %s  \n",num_lines,yytext); }

"\n" { num_lines++; }

 " "
 "\t"
 "\r"

 . { printf("ERROR %d:Unidentified symbol: %s \n",num_lines,yytext);}

 %%

 int main(int argc,char **argv)
 {
++argv,--argc;
if(argc>0) 
    yyin=fopen(argv[0],"r");
else
    yyin=stdin;
yylex();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is significant in a lex pattern.  `a | b` is not the same as `a|b`.  In the troublesome pattern, you have whitespace that I don't think you intended.

That said, in my opinion, your 3-pattern solution is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: As you said whitespace was the problem.Thanks.